# react-query: QueryOptions not working when using userQueries()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-query

When passing some "query options" while using `useQueries()` to fetch multiples queries at the same time, these "query options" are not been applied on any query execution (eg:        `refetchOnWindowFocus` is `true` and I want it to be `false`).

Example

```
const slidesID = ['11111', '22222', '33333'];

const COMMON_QUERY_OPTIONS = {
        retry: false,
        refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
        refetchOnMount: false,
    } as const;

    const slideQueries = useQueries(
        slidesID.map((slideID) => {
            return {
                queryKey: ['slides', 'slide', slideID],
                queryFn: () => getSlide(slideID),
                COMMON_QUERY_OPTIONS,
            };
        }),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are passing in the WRONG way the "query options".

There are two similar but different ways of executing [useQuery](https://tanstack.com/query/v3/docs/react/reference/useQuery):

a) common way ( just the 3er param is an {object} )

```
const result = useQuery(queryKey,queryFn, {
        retry: false,
        refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
        refetchOnMount: false,
    } )
```

b) the object syntax way (all the params are at the same level inside a global object)

```
const result = useQuery({queryKey, queryFn, retry: false,
        refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
        refetchOnMount: false,
    })
```

In your example, you are using the 'the object syntax way' but passing the "query options" as the 'common way'. To fix it just apply a ...spread to correctly pass the options.

FIXED Example

```
const slidesID = ['11111', '22222', '33333'];

const COMMON_QUERY_OPTIONS = {
        retry: false,
        refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
        refetchOnMount: false,
    } as const;

    const slideQueries = useQueries(
        slidesID.map((slideID) => {
            return {
                queryKey: ['slides', 'slide', slideID],
                queryFn: () => getSlide(slideID),
                ...COMMON_QUERY_OPTIONS, //notice the ... here
            };
        }),
    );
```